# React Native + Firebase: cache files on device to save bandwidth + make available offline

Tags: firebase, react-native

I'm building a small app for storage of image files- think scans of certificates etc. All stored in Firebase.

Every time I load an image on a screen, Firebase seems to fetch it from my storage bucket, rather than from on the device- even if it's already been loaded on that device. This isn't ideal, seems like it's going to chew a heap of mobile data, and the files need to be available offline.

Am I missing something in my firebase config to set this up- some kind of file caching on device?

Answer (score 0):

There is no local or offline cache for files downloaded from Cloud Storage using the Firebase JavaScript SDK, other than what's provided by the browser when making normal HTTP requests using the normal methods to fetch data from URLs.  If you are downloading data using a [download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url), then you are depending on the browser to implement any caching.

Comment: Seems that there's some support for downloading files along how I'm thinking: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#download_to_a_local_file
 and https://rnfirebase.io/reference/storage/reference#writeToFile- it mentions downloading for offline use.

Comment: Perhaps I'll have a play, I might see if I can add an "available offline" checkbox, and mirror the structure locally, check the local storage first. Was just assuming someone would have come across this before